# Find number of solutions to the equation?

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of distinct ways to make a sum N using numbers given numbers $a_1,a_2,a_3...a_k$ where $1\le k\le n$ .Here $a_1,a_2,...a_k$ can be used more than once.

Example: If N=19 and the available numbers are 4 and 5 then the no. of ways are 4 because
of distinct ways [4,5,5,5],[5,4,5,5],[5,5,4,5] and [5,5,5,4].

Note:- Here each and every order is counted different. Eg:-(1,2,2) and (2,2,1) are not same.

My approach :-In the very beginning I wrote an equation which is

$a_1*x_1+a_2*x_2+a_3*x_3+a_4*x_4....+a_k*x_k=N$

where $x_1,x_2....x_k$ are parameters and $a_1,a_2,a_3...a_k$ are known coefficients.

Then I substituted $a_j*x_j$ as $X_j$ where $1 \le j \le k$.

Then this equation became

$X_1+X_2+...X_K=N$

which I compared with the theorem of [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29). But I'm not getting the required answer.

Comment: Do you mean natural numbers?

Comment: No it need not be natural numbers.It can be zero as well i.e the use of particular number in making the sum can be Zero as well.

Comment: What you suggested ignores the order, it just looks the number of partitions available.
For your example you would get $1$ instead of $4$

Comment: Snufsan I want to consider each and every different order.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the problem, ignoring order, is a 'money changing' problem: ways to make change for 19 units using 4 and 5 unit coins.
This is solved using a generating function $\frac{1}{\left(1-l_4 x^4\right) \left(1-l_5 x^5\right)}$ where we take the coefficient of x^19 and get $l_4 l_5^3$
The second part is calculating the multiplicity of each solution (here we only have a single term, generally we get many terms). This is simply the multinomial of the exponent-set :
here $(4;1,3)$ equals 4.
 As an extra example, take N=12 and parts (2,3,4) ; you get
$l_2^6+l_4 l_2^4+l_3^2 l_2^3+l_4^2 l_2^2+l_3^2 l_4 l_2+l_3^4+l_4^3$ with multiplicities
$\{1,10,1,5,12,6,1\}$ for a total of 36.